# how to display CSS button in High Contast Mode

Tags: css

I am using below CSS to display button. When i switch to Windows High Contrast Mode, buttons become invisible. how do i fix this issue?

```
.button
{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,  #d3d3d3,  #fff);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d3d3d3');
    color: #005694;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

I tried giving .button:BEFORE but with that i see normal button and sytles are not getting applied on it.

Please help me with some tips to fix this issue.

thanks

Comment: OS, Browser, etc?
Also, you're developing a high contrast mode to your site, or you mean something like Windows' High Contrast system themes?

Comment: Perhaps this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091676/what-actually-happens-to-css-in-high-contrast-mode

Comment: our site should be compliant with Accessibility (508 compliance) and as per that all buttons, icons, text should be visible in windows high contrast mode. Hope this helps

Comment: One problem I see with your CSS is that it doesn't set a background color explicitly on browsers that don't recognise the properties you use. If you give the button a fallback background color like `#E9E9E9`, at least it will be constant and not depend on the system colors.

Answer (score 0):

Any Background you specify in the class will not work in WHCM There are two way two way to display to fix WHCM

```
<input type="image" src="images/arrow.png" />
```

And second is - CSS Content

**Code:**

```
<button type="button">
<span class="whmcbtn"></span>
</button>
```

**Class:**

```
.whmcbtn:before { content: url(images/arrow.png);}
```

This only the way to fix WHCM for inputs and buttons